# How to change a URL using .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, url

I don't know anything about coding, but I really want to change the URL of my pages:

- `site/data/9/Symbian-3rd-Apps.html` to `site/symbian_applications.html`
- `site/data/file/352/Core-Video-Player-Symbian-3rd--sisx.html` to `site/Core-Video-Player-Symbian-3rd--sisx.html`

Answer (score 1):

This topic on Stack Overflow may be useful: [how to change URL using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301249/how-to-change-url-htacces).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to change a URL in *.htaccess* is to rename the file to the new name and then put in command to redirect the old URL to the new.

So first your would rename `site/data/9/Symbian-3rd-Apps.html` to `site/symbian_applications.html`.  Then you would put the following redirect rule in *.htaccess* (with your actual domain name rather than example.com):

```
redirect permanent site/data/9/Symbian-3rd-Apps.html http://example.com/site/symbian_applications.html
```